# Flipping image bytes horizontally

Tags: c#, image-processing

It seems that none of the previous postes on this topic covers how to flip image **bytes** horizontally. The postes I've read only covers the `ScaleTransform` and similar things. Basically, I want flip the raw bytes of a `32 bpp image`. The code beneath works for `8 bpp`.

```
var outarray = new byte[_sourceimg.Binary.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < _sourceimg.PixelWidth; i++)
{
  for (var j = 0; j < _sourceimg.PixelHeight; j++)
  {
    var index = _sourceimg.PixelWidth - 1 - (i + j*_sourceimg.PixelWidth;
    outarray[i + j * _sourceimg.PixelWidth] = _sourceimg.Binary[index];
  }
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the stride to adapt this code for 32 bpp. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't you use : var outarray = new uint[_sourceimg.Binary.Length];

Comment: You'll have to assign *four* elements in outarray for each pixel.  Many better ways to do this, you got into this pickle by trying to support 8bpp.

Comment: This doesn't look like `System.Drawing.Bitmap`... what exactly is this? Because your `index` calculation should indeed use the stride, not the width. If all else fails you can probably just divide the data length by the height to get that stride.

Comment: Also, actually using `x` and `y` as loop variables makes code like this about a million times easier to read. I also advise making y the outer loop, so your arrays are actually accessed in normal order. Much easier to debug.